# Consultar usuario no SQLite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Preciso validar um usuário no banco de dados. Caso seja válido, quero chamar a segunda Activity.

Qual método usar para fazer essa validação no banco de dados do android?

Código onde é feita a inserção:

```
public String insereProfessor(Professor professor) {
    ContentValues valores;
    long resultado = 1;

    dataBase = bancoDados.getWritableDatabase();
    valores = new ContentValues();
    valores.put("CODPROF", professor.getCodProfessor());
    valores.put("NOME", professor.getNomeProfessor());
    valores.put("USUARIO", professor.getUsuario());
    valores.put("SENHA", professor.getSenha());

    resultado = dataBase.replaceOrThrow("PROFESSOR", null, valores);
    dataBase.close();

    if (resultado == -1)
        return "Erro de registro";
    else
        return "Registro Inserido com sucesso";

}
```

Tentei autenticá-lo da seguinte forma:

```
public Professor consutaProfessorNoBanco(String usuario, String senha) {

    try {
        String SQL = "select CODPROF, NOME, USUARIO, SENHA from PROFESSOR where USUARIO = ? and SENHA = ? ";
        String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{usuario, senha};
        Cursor cursor = dataBase.rawQuery(SQL, selectionArgs);

        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                professor.setCodProfessor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("CODPROF")));
                professor.setNomeProfessor(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("NOME")));
                professor.setUsuario(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("USUARIO")));
                professor.setSenha(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("SENHA")));
            }
        }
        cursor.close();

    } catch (Exception erro) {
        Log.i("Erro ocnsulta", "Erro consultar no banco");
    }

    return professor;
}
```

Comment: Qual código você está usando pra criação do banco? é alguma lib, como o cupBoard, por exemplo? Sem ver o seu código não podemos te ajudar.

Comment: Editei o topico com o codigo.

Comment: Cadê o código que cria o banco?

Comment: O que queres dizer com "validar um usuário no banco"? Verificar se ele já existe?